# SQL Server window functions for each min and max date in one record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I am trying to get everything I need in one row for each partition against the opportunity.

I have the below example where I just want to return the Min and Max for each value in the `Service_Appointment` column in one row so I can query this as part of another dataset. I need it to be in one row that's why I am using a `row_number` function to query `where RN = 1`

There are many rows return against an opportunity, what I am trying to do is all the Min and Max for each appointment type using the `Createdon`.

Here is the example data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable 
(
     [ActivityId] int, 
     [OpportunityId] int, 
     [Appointment_Service] nvarchar(255), 
     [CreatedOn] datetime, 
     [Appt_Booked_Date] datetime, 
     [Appointment_State] nvarchar(255), 
     [Appointment_Status] nvarchar(255), 
     [RN] bigint, 
     [LASTEST_First_Appointment] datetime, 
     [LASTEST_Second_Appointment] datetime 
)

INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
    (4176537, 105994, N'1st Appointment', N'2015-01-27T00:00:00', N'2015-01-27T00:00:00', N'Closed', N'Attended', 1, N'2015-01-27T00:00:00', N'2017-11-21T11:25:46' ), 
    (4176536, 105994, N'2nd Appointment', N'2015-01-28T00:00:00', N'2015-01-28T00:00:00', N'Closed', N'Attended', 2, N'2015-01-28T00:00:00', N'2017-11-21T11:25:46' ), 
    (19656494, 105994, N'Other Appointment', N'2017-03-31T15:33:26',  N'2017-03-31T15:33:26', N'Scheduled', N'In Progress', 3, N'2017-11-21T11:25:46', N'2017-11-21T11:25:46' ), 
    (9394803, 105994, N'Other Appointment', N'2017-04-28T06:38:56', N'2017-04-28T06:38:56', N'Scheduled', N'In Progress', 4, N'2017-11-21T11:25:46', N'2017-11-21T11:25:46' ), 
    (3774963, 105994, N'Other Appointment', N'2017-04-28T17:20:06', N'2017-04-28T17:20:06', N'Scheduled', N'In Progress', 5, N'2017-11-21T11:25:46', N'2017-11-21T11:25:46' )
```

This is my query

```
SELECT  
    ActivityId, OpportunityId,
    Appointment_Service, CreatedOn,
    Appt_Booked_Date, 
    Appointment_State, Appointment_Status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OpportunityId ORDER BY CreatedOn, ActivityId) AS RN,
    LAST_VALUE(CreatedOn) OVER (PARTITION BY Appointment_Service ORDER BY CreatedOn, ActivityId ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LASTEST_First_Appointment
FROM    
    dbo.DIM_APPOINTMENT
```

There are 3 different appointment, so I just want the First 1st appoint, last 1st appointment (if any exist), first 2nd appointment and last 2nd appointment, the same with other appointments. When I have all the columns I need, I can just query the row_number field to bring back RN = 1 and that will bring everything I need, well at least that's the plan lol, thank you in advance

Comment: Would you provide sample output please ?

Comment: Your table has no `service_appointment` column.

Answer (score 0):

I went with a simpler data set for my testing:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
      (
          Id       INT
         ,category INT
         ,x        INT
      );

INSERT INTO @test
     (
         Id
        ,category
        ,x
     )
VALUES
     (1, 1, 1)
    ,(1, 1, 2)
    ,(1, 1, 3)
    ,(1, 1, 4)
    ,(1, 2, 5)
    ,(1, 2, 6)
    ,(1, 2, 7)
    ,(1, 2, 8);
```

When I ran your code it looked like you where partitioning on the wrong column (that or I just wasn't keeping your example straight in my head). In this dataset category stands in for appointment type.

Then we just need to get our fist and last set up correctly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.Id
   ,t.category
   ,firstX = FIRST_VALUE(x) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, category ORDER BY x)
   ,lastX = LAST_VALUE(x) OVER (PARTITION BY Id
                                            ,category
                                    ORDER BY x
                                    RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                               )
  FROM @test AS t;
```

Here are the results:

```
Id  category    firstX  lastX
1   1           1       4
1   2           5       8
```

Then pivot the result set:

```
WITH cte_last
    AS (
           SELECT DISTINCT
               t.Id
              ,t.category
              ,firstX = FIRST_VALUE(x) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, category ORDER BY x)
              ,lastX = LAST_VALUE(x) OVER (PARTITION BY Id
                                                       ,category
                                               ORDER BY x
                                               RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                          )
             FROM @test AS t
       )
SELECT l.Id
      ,cat1First = SUM(CASE l.category WHEN 1 THEN l.firstX ELSE 0 END)
      ,cat1Last = SUM(CASE l.category WHEN 1 THEN l.lastX ELSE 0 END)
      ,cat2First = SUM(CASE l.category WHEN 2 THEN l.firstX ELSE 0 END)
      ,cat2Last = SUM(CASE l.category WHEN 2 THEN l.lastX ELSE 0 END)
  FROM cte_last AS l
 GROUP BY Id;
```

And you get this:

```
Id  cat1First   cat1Last    cat2First   cat2Last
1   1           4           5           8
```